# Hopf algebra of representative k-valued functions of an abstract group

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, hopf-algebras

Let $G$ be an abstract group. If we can embed $G$ into a group $H$, in a way that we had $G$ and $H$ of the same Hopf algebra of representative $k$-valued functions ($R(G)\sim R(H)$ as Hopf algebras). My question is when can we have $G$ isomorphic to $H$ ? What sufficient conditions, if needed, to have this? Thanks

Comment: One can check that the group like elements in $R(G)$ and $R(H)$ are precisely $G$ and $H$. Hence any Hopf algebra isomorphism of $R(G)$ and $R(H)$ factors as a group isomorphism of $G$ and $H$.

Comment: What is "the Hopf algebra of $k$-valued functions" if $G$ is infinite?

Comment: I suppose it is understood as the algebra of finitely supported functions.

Comment: @Sein: Probably, but then the grouplike elements are the homomorphisms $G\rightarrow k$, which do not suffice to recover $G$.

Comment: Yes i in fact meant the hopf algebra of representative functions. @sein does this deal of searching grouplike elements works for the hopf algebra of representative functions? Or your answer was for the group algebra maybe! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question is not well formulated because you don't define $R(G)$. Also it is not clear to me what you want to know,since your "if" clause has no "then" clause.

I assume you mean the Hopf algebra of representative functions not the group algebra since you can recover $G$ as the grouplikes in the group ring.

So $R(G)$ consists of the functions which generate a finite dimensional submodule of $k^G$ under the natural module structure.  Your question is essentially answered in [Hopf dual of the Hopf dual](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308374/hopf-dual-of-the-hopf-dual).  There are finitely generated groups with no non-trivial finite dimensional representations. For instance any finitely generated infinite simple group has no non-trivial finite dimensional reps  finitely generated linear groups are residually finite by Malcev. So only constant functions are representative.

So you can take Thompson's groups $T$ and $V$. They are infinite simple finitely generated groups and $T$ is contained in $V$.  They are not isomorphic. I'm not sure you can find decent sufficient conditions outside of both groups being finite.

Comment: Yes i mean hopf algebra of representative functions, if we take in particular the context of tannaka-krein duality, and G a group embedded in the characters group X(R(G)) of R(G), such that R(G) is isomorphic to R(X(R(G)) as hopf algebras, does this implies that G isomorphic to X(R(G)) ?

Comment: But XR(G) is commutative is it not? So why would G be embedded in XR(G)?

Comment: no it is not commutative unless G is, as in fact it is a group under the convolution product

Comment: And G i can suppose that it is embedded in it under some assumption on G.

Comment: How do you define the convolution of characters so that you get another character?

Comment: I think only pointwise product of characters gives you a character.

Comment: Let T and S two characters, i.e algebra maps from R(G) to k. Then (T*S)(f)=m(T \tensor S) \delta (f), for all f \in R(G)

Comment: I see.  You want characters of R(G) not G

Comment: Exactly @Benjamin